# repetition of permutations problems bingo

Tags: permutations

for a game bingo, organizers place one marble with 0 marble on it, one marble with 1, and one marble with 2 and so on up to one marble with 9. Each time a number is called one number is drawn, the digit showing recorded, the marble replaced and another marble is drawn, the digit recorded, the marble replaced and another marble is drawn, the digit recorded and the marble replaced, the number is then :

10 x first digit  + second digit, for example 3  7 is 37

If the number has already been called that draw is considered null. If the first digit is 9 the number is only called if the second digit is 0, otherwise the draw is null. (there are only 90 numbers in a game of bingo.)

is this reasonable way of drawing numbers 1-90 for a bingo game? if not, suggest modifications.

my solution: yes, because 1-90 are all even chances

Comment: quite a long question, eh~ >_< haha

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Comment: ooh oops sorry, i'll add it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since odds of getting $90$ is $\large\frac{1}{10}$ as opposed to other numbers from $1$ to $89$ whose odds are clearly less than that of $90$

And drawing balls in your case is actually affected by results in past. For example if you've recorded all numbers from $20$ to $29$ Now you're not allowed to draw marble marked $2$ on it for first draw, I mean even if you're drawing it you're making it a NULL draw

Comment: @carry Thanks You're first to upvote since I've reached $1$k

Comment: don't worry, i am the who should say thanks for helping :D